# pioneer 3at+kinect

Tags: simulation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have to do a job where I have to simulate a Pioneer 3AT robot carrying a camera integrated kinect, libraries and software that I use? some manual that can help me?

Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33459/pioneer-3at+kinect/) by [jmm89](https://answers.ros.org/users/2296/jmm89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
P3AT can be used with the help of [P2OS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20p2os).
Kinect can be used with the help of [openni_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect) package.
I suggest you to try them individually and test the packages to have a feel of it.
Then you may have to setup the tf frames as indicated in this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF). So that you have a transformation between the robot and the kinect.

I hope this should be your starting point to get started with what you have in your question.

Hope it helps.

Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1